# How to pass a multidimensional array into constructors?

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I'm declate the multidimensional array `propertyArray = new int[numbHuman][40]`

where `[numbHuman]` is the number of rows, and the `[40]` is the number of columns (or vice versa doesnt really matter). Anyway I create those propertyArray's in a nested for loop, but I'm not sure How I'd pass propertyArray[][] into the player object constructor. Here is my code, I will try to clarify if needed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class PlayerArray
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int numbHuman;
    private Player[] arr;
    private String[] userName;
    //private 
    private int[] testArray;
    private int[][] propertyArray;
    private int[] userID;
    private int startingMoney;
    private int startingPosition;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private int i;
    //private int d;
    public PlayerArray()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many players wish to play? Values of 2 through 8 accepted.");
        numbHuman = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numbHuman + " players selected.");
        while (numbHuman < 2 || numbHuman > 8)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");
            numbHuman = scan.nextInt();
        }       
        arr = new Player[numbHuman];
        i=0;
        testArray = new int[40];
        propertyArray = new int[numbHuman][40];///// WORK ON DIS 
        userName = new String[numbHuman];
        userID = new int[numbHuman];
        startingMoney = 1500;
        startingPosition = 0;
        b=0;
        c=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {

            userID[i] = b;
            System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + ", Please enter your first name:");
            userName[i] = scan.next();

            for(c = 0; c < 40; c++)
            { 
                propertyArray[i][c] = 0;
            }

            arr[i] = new Player(userName[i],startingMoney,userID[i],startingPosition,propertyArray[i][c]);
            b++;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to pass it into, how do i go about this? All the other variables work but the multidimensional array.

```
public Player(String userName, int changeInMoney, int userID, int startingPosition, int[][]propertyArray)
    {
        myID = userID;
        myName = userName;
        currentPosition += startingPosition;
        currentBal -= payBank(changeInMoney);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: it might be better *not* to provide all that input prompting inside the array class itself.

Comment: EDIT just updated last lines of First class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a set of square brackets for each dimension, e.g.:

```
public Player(String userName, int changeInMoney, int userID, 
    int startingPosition, int[][] propertyArray)
```

Comment: Sorry I accidently left out a small portion of significant code, it should be arr[i] = new Player(userName[i],startingMoney,userID[i],startingPosition, propertyArray[i][c]);

Comment: @BrothahHeffay it makes no difference, you need to redefine the constructor to match the prototype above in order to accept a two dimensional array.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did that as well, let me update my code again XD And it still won't compile, complains that "actual argument int cannot be converted to int[][] by method invocation conversion"

Comment: @BrothahHeffay Sorry, re-reading your line of code, you're not actually passing a two dimensional array, `propertyArray[i][c]` is a single element (i.e. an `int`). Maybe you mean to call this as: `arr[i] = new Player(userName[i],startingMoney,userID[i],startingPosition, propertyArray);`

Comment: My intentions are to give each `Player` a corresponding array, where each index contains a 0. I'm starting to think I'm approaching the problem wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra pair of brackets:

```
public Player(String userName, int changeInMoney, int userID, int startingPosition, int[][] propertyArray)
```